# When to use the terms python shell and python interpreter?

Tags: python, shell, interpreter

1) I am new to Python and love to learn its core. I have downloaded the python software package and discovered the python.exe application inside. I double clicked it and a balck and white window popped up. 
[image]
Should I call it a python Interpreter or python Shell?

2) I am learning python online. I came across the terms python tty, python shell and python interpreter. I am satisfied by calling that screen inside the window as a tty(TeleTYpewriter) because we could use only keyboard to work inside and no mouse. But actually that screen has got some intelligence responding to our request. Is python tty an apt term for it?

3) In UNIX, shell is an user interface and command line interpreter, so does python interpreter and python shell are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Python shell lets you use the Python interpreter in interactive mode, just as an OS shell, such as bash, lets you use the OS in interactive mode. You can use the Python interpreter in script mode or batch mode wherein you let the interpreter execute all lines of code in one sequence. It is comparable to writing shell scripts (or batch files in Microsoft Windows).

In your case the screenshot is of a python "shell".

You shouldn't really pay attention to this distinction because in the end everything runs through the python interpreter be it in interactive mode or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is both the python shell and the python interpreter. The shell is where you write your code directly in the CLI, whereas the interpreter is the program that will interpret your code and execute it. Therefore, the interpreter is called in the shell when you write some code, it may also be called when you execute some python code directly from a file.

Comment: "it may also be called when you execute some python code directly from a file" also valid for pyhton default IDE(I mean IDLE)??

Answer (score 0):

The customary term for the interactive Python shell is the Python REPL. Many modern interpreters enter a Read-Eval-Print-Loop when you run them interactively, and this term has stuck.

The program which interprets and executes your Python code is the Python interpreter; it can act as a shell, as described above, or run silently and just execute your Python code without any visible user interface of its own, like when you run a script of yours with

```
python scriptname.py
```

Comment: That sounds correct to me, yes. You can argue that the *program* which does the printing is the Python interpreter, but the interpreter is a separate component within that program.

Comment: So,  I conclude python shell is an user interface with an interpreter like normal OS shell.  So the window screen is  python shell with interpreter in it.

Comment: The REPL shell is the right term;  interpreter obviously comes behind it.  I have upvoted you,  since my score is less than 15 it is not displayed

Comment: The window in your screen shot actually looks like a Windows `cmd` instance, though I guess Python on Windows launches inside that if it's not connected to any terminal device.

Comment: That's not a cmd instance of window.  That window is appears when I double click python.exe inside the Python folder.

Comment: I (luckily) don't have access to Windows so I can't investigate. My impression is that it runs something like `cmd /c python.exe` but I could be wrong.